# Solve the differential equation $y''=y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

## Problem

Solve the differential equation $y''=y$.

## Solution

Obviously, $y=0$ is a particular solution. If $y \neq 0$, then we denote $y'=\dfrac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=:p$. Then $y''=\dfrac{{\rm d}p}{{\rm d}x}=\dfrac{{\rm d}p}{{\rm d}y}\cdot \dfrac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=p\cdot\dfrac{{\rm d}p}{{\rm d}y}$. Hence, we have
$$p\cdot\dfrac{{\rm d}p}{{\rm d}y}=y$$
Separating the variables, we have
$$p{\rm d}p=y{\rm d}y$$
Integrating the both sides, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}p^2=\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}C_1$$
If $C_1 \neq 0$, then
$$p=\pm \sqrt{y^2+C_1}$$
This is exactly
$$\dfrac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=\pm \sqrt{y^2+C_1}$$
Separating the variables again, we have
$$\dfrac{{\rm d}y}{\pm \sqrt{y^2+C_1}}={\rm d}x$$
Integrating the both sides, we have
$$\pm {\rm arsh} \frac{y}{\sqrt{C_1}}=x+C_2 (C_1>0) $$
$\cdots$
This is too complicated! Any simpler method?

Comment: $y= e^x$ and $y=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Does $y=e^x$ suffice? What about $y=e^{-x}$?

Comment: What in $y(x)=a\sinh(x+b)$ is too complicated? You need the second variant $y(x)=a\cosh(x+b)$ to cover all sign combinations in the coefficients of $y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Make the ansatz $$y=e^{\lambda x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$y''=y$ is a constant coefficient, homogenous, second order, linear differential equation,

which can be written as $(D^2-1)y=0$, where $D$ is the differential operator $\dfrac d{dx}.$

This can be factored  as $(D+1)(D-1)y=0,$ so the answer is a linear combination

of solutions to $(D+1)y=0  $ and $(D-1)y=0 ; $ i.e., $y=Ae^{-x}+Be^x.$

Answer (score 0):

It is easier, following your route, to multiply the original equation by $y'$ to obtain $y'y''=yy'$ and integrate to get $y'^2=y^2+C$, but as others have said this is not the way to go.

The other solutions give neat ways through, which you will eventually need to know. Here is a way through which can be adapted to prove that the shorter methods work  (you'll have to work through it, as it is a sketch, and I hope you will then understand how the pieces fit together)

---

Suppose you have the equation $z'=az$ and let $z=e^{ax}w$ then $ae^{ax}w+e^{ax}w'=ae^{ax}w$ from which you see that $w'=0$ and $w$ is constant.

In your original equation add $y'$ to each side, and set $z=y+y'$. Then you find $z'=z$ so that $y+y'=Ae^x$

Next subtract $y'$ from each side and set $z=y'-y$. This gives you $z'=-z$ so that $y'-y=Be^{-x}$

Now subtract the second of these from the first to obtain $2y=Ae^x-Be^{-x}$